# Best class library project for ASP.NET Core v1.1?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Well, I know the ASP.NET Core v1.1 is fresh, but I am little playing a with it and  I am a bit confused about the right class library project choosing in the solution. So here is a scenario:

I start in the Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core web application project template and choose sub-branch  **ASP.NET Core** (= not with .NET Framework).
Ok, than I would like to add a class library project, but there are two possibilities:

- .NET Core Library
- .NET Standard Library

Well, ASP.NET Core v1.0 did not support common class libraries, but it seems v1.1 have no problem with that. So result is, I can reference both types.

So my question - is it ok to reference .NET Standard Library to ASP.NET Core project? Or should I reference .NET Core Library only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .NET Standard Library with .Net Core 1.0.  The Standard library is trying to set a common API for the cross platform .net APIs.

You could use it in your project to get experience with it, but choose what makes sense for your class requirements and timeline.

[This site has a good article on .NET Standard Library](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2016/11/24/net-standard-what-it-is-and-how-it-applies-to-net-core/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and useful article. I have missed .NET Standard is another type od libraries, I thought that it is common class library, now I see.